# How to refresh a subquery if text is written in a textbox?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a form with a textbox and a subquery. The textbox filters the subquery but everytime I write what I want to filter I have to tab out of the textbox and press the "refresh all" button.
I want to know how I can make it so that whenever I write something in the textbox the subquery updates and filters accordingly.
I should also mention that I am using Microsoft Access 2007 and my form looks like this : https://imgur.com/a/DpQ7p.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Change event of the Textbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Change()
    With Me
        If Len(.TextBox.Text) = 0 Then
            .SubForm.Form.FilterOn = False
        Else
            .SubForm.Form.Filter = "[FieldName] Like '*" & .TextBox.Text & "*'"
            .SubForm.Form.FilterOn = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Update:

```
Private Sub Text4_Change()
    With Me
        If Len(.Text4.Text) > 0 Then
            .[Kupci Query subform].Form.Requery
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My knowlage of sql and access is minimal so if you could give me some additional information (what I need to change in the code to make it word for me) I would appreciate it. My textbox name is "Text4" and my subquery name is "CustomersQ". Thank you for the answer.

Comment: See updated answer. When the TextBox control changes (by typing into it), the subform gets updated by requiring its source. Change 'SubForm' to the name of your control and test.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but every time I write something in the textbox an error pops up. Here are some screenshots that I took : http://imgur.com/a/nuyvi. I'm sorry for being annoying, but I really want this to work. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: I cannot see the images at work, can you post your code and the error message?

Comment: I opened the design view clicked on the textbox, clicked on the on change event and made a code builder with the code :
"Private Sub Text4_Change()
    With Me
        If Len(.Text4.Text) > 0 Then
            .SubForm.Form.Requery [Kupci Query subform].
        End If
    End With
End Sub"

Every time I change something in the textbox I get an error : 
"Compile error : Syntax error" and the .SubForm... is highlighted.
My query name is "KupciQ" my form name is "Form1" my textbox name is "Text4" and my subform name is "Kupci Query subform" (Kupci means customers).

Comment: My query has 5 columns, in order (translations are in brackets) : "ID", "Ime" (name), "Prezime" (last name), "Grad" (town/city) and "Datum" (date).
The code that I'm using to filter the query is : "
SELECT * FROM Kupci 
WHERE Forms.[Form1].[Text4] IS NULL OR (Forms.[Form1].[Text4] = Forms.[Form1].[Text4] AND Ime=Forms.[Form1].[Text4]);
".
I have also reuploaded the images to this link : https://imgur.com/a/wdwcF.

Comment: Change `.SubForm.Form.Requery` to `.[Kupci Query subform].Form.Requery`.

Comment: I have changed the code to : "
Private Sub Text4_Change()
    With Me
        If Len(.Text4.Text) > 0 Then
            .[Kupci Query subform].Form.Requery [Kupci Query subform].
            End If
    End With
End Sub
"
but I still get the same error whenever I try to write or delete something.

Comment: You have an error in your code - use code from updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *OnChange* event of the textbox and filter on the *Text* property:

```
Me!SubformControlName.Form.Filter = "[SomeField] = '" & Me!YourTextbox.Text & "*'"
Me!SubformControlName.Form.FilterOn = True
```

or perhaps:

```
Me!SubformControlName.Form.Requery
```